# How can I reset game using this function in corona?

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

### Okay so I have a game that goes like this in Corona:

```
     //this is main.lua

local function game()
//game is here which contains mainly display objects

     local function reset()
     //here i remove all the display objects and cancel timers
     //and then call the game function again
     game()
     end
end
```

### game()

So basically in reset function I call the game() function again.
But due to this, after a few resets the game becomes slow which I think is because of all functions being pushed on top of one another and no function "returning". So, is there any solution to what I want to do but without slowing the game?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to do this way. Remove  local from variables and first function if you get error.

```
local function game()
//game is here which contains mainly display objects

end

local function reset()
   //here i remove all the display objects and cancel timers
  //and then call the game function again
  game()
end
```